# Bigquery: Group query results in arrays

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that lists friends from a particular user:

user_id | friend_name

1       | JOEL

1       | JACK

2       | MARIA

I want to have them grouped by user_id and each row has an array with all the friends.

How can make a selection that would do this transformation?

UPDATE:

select user_id, array_agg(friend_name) as friends
from your_table
group by user_id

Works fine.

However I forgot a small detail, the table has another column.

user_id | friend_name | friends_age

1       | JOEL   | 21

1       | JACK   | 30

2       | MARIA  | 25

My solution was to add another array_agg:

```
select user_id, array_agg(friend_name),  array_agg(friend_age)as friends
from your_table
group by user_id
```

I believe it works, the only problem is when age is Null, in that case, I need to add a CASE WHEN clause.

```
select user_id, array_agg(friend_name),  
array_agg(CASE friend_age IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE friend_age END)as friends
from your_table
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select user_id, array_agg(friend_name) as friends
from your_table
group by user_id
```

Comment: Thank you. I add more details. Could you tell me if my solution for NULL values is correct and if the index of the arrays will align?

Comment: as of handling NULL values  - I would use less verbose version - `array_agg(ifnull(friend_age, 0))`

Comment: as of index alignment - no - they will not - at least order is not guaranteed! to make sure they will - you need to add some order by - for example `array_agg(friend_name order by friend_name, friend_age)` and `array_agg(friend_age order by friend_name, friend_age)`

Comment: or ... you can have both friend_name and friend_age in same array - `array_agg(struct(friend_name, friend_age))`

Comment: nice, that is exaclty what I wanted. Thank you again.